# как правильно передать byte[]?

Tags: java, android

Такая проблема, я передаю фото которое получаю с камеры между активити. Делаю это с помощью `Intent`

вот так

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AcceptNotAccept.class);
Image image = (Image) msg.obj;
ByteBuffer buffer = image.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
buffer.get(bytes);
intent.putExtra("bytesImage", bytes);

startActivity(intent);
```

на что получаю такую ошибку

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
```

Насколько я понял это происходит из за того, что `Intent` не может передавать большой поток `byte[]` (видимо фото много весит) и вот теперь вопрос, как сжать массив `byte` чтоб передать его в другое активити и желательно, чтоб не терять качество изображения?

Я читал что вроде это можно сделать как то с помощью кэша? или просто сжать фото? Посоветуйте кто разбирается

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в том, что BINDER ограничен в передачи файлов в 1МБ, поэтому могу предожить пару решений.

1) "Я читал что вроде это можно сделать как то с помощью кэша" Всё верно, можно сделать через кэш, а именно вы создадите временный файл и передадите не сам файл, а лишь только путь к нему.

2) Создать [MemoryFile](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/os/MemoryFile.html#MemoryFile(java.lang.String,%20int)) и передать дескриптор файла, а уже зная дескриптор вы можете получить ваш файл, собственно этот вариант обычно и предлагается при таких вопросах